# Can't launch Spyder (Anaconda)

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, spyder, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm having the next issue when I try to launch Spyder:

```
$spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/luisquii/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 22, in <module>
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ImportError: libXss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/luisquii/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/luisquii/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 186, in main
from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/home/luisquii/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 90, in <module>
from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets  # analysis:ignore
  File "/home/luisquii/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 26, in <module>
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage as QWebEnginePage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets'
```

I'm running it on Windows Subsystem For Linux terminal.

Even if I run it like:

```
$ anaconda-navigator
```

and then click "Launch" in the Anaconda interface I got the same error message in a textbox.

Do you know how to fix this issue?

If you need any extra information I can provide it.

Comment: check if pyqt is installed or not

Answer (score 1):

Solved by:

```
sudo apt-get install libxss1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error.

I got Spyder to work on **Windows Subsystem for Linux** through a clean reinstall of Anaconda3 followed by:

```
sudo apt-get install libxtst6
sudo updatedb
sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins
```

make sure you have xming installed